# Python hex to int conversion error

Tags: python, int, hex

```
>>> print(int(0x51))
```

81

This is correct.

```
>>> str = 51
>>> cmd = "0x%s" %(str)
>>> print(int(cmd))
```

But why is this incorrect?
I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x51'

Comment: `0x51` is already an integer (expressed in hexadecimal), and so is `51`, but have different values.

Answer (score 9):

`0x51` is a Python integer literal, it itself *already* produces an integer:

```
>>> 0x51
81
```

See the [*Integer and long integer literals* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) for the details; this is the `hexinteger` form. Calling `int()` on that integer object just returns the same integer value again.

You *can* use `int()` on a string with the prefix `0x`, but you need to tell it to use `0` as the base:

```
>>> int('0x51', 0)
81
```

`0` is a special case here; it tells `int()` to look for Python integer literal prefixes such as `0x` to determine the real base from that. From the [`int()` documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

> Base 0 means to interpret the string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16.